# add character after each word in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-edittext

i need to add a $ after each set of numbers a user enters in a edit text. For example as soon as a user enters a number the $ should be automatically placed in front of that number. I tried to use a textwatcher were i get the current string then add a $ and set the text of the edittext. When i do that the keyboard freezes.

Comment: Impement a [textwatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: Can you post the code of the textwatcher? A common mistake is to make a change to the text in `EditText` inside the textwatcher which fires the `onTextChanged` which changes the text again etc. etc. It is possible you have entered a loop. You should first remove the text watcher `yourEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);`, then make your changes, then add the textwatcher back in `yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);` - all inside the `onTextChanged` method.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you have entered a infinite loop inside the `onTextChanged` method of your `textwatcher`. You need to remove the listener first, then make your changes, then re-add the listener:

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // Remove TextChangedlistener so that this function does not
        // enter an infinite loop when we change it in code!
        yourEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        // Add your code to insert the '$' symbol here


        // Re-add listener
        yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        // This just moves the cursor back to the end of the input
        yourEditText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()); 

    }
```